# Can you use SmartStore when using Hybrid Remote?

Tags: hybrid

I recently found a [webinar](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ipzK8Jok2gM) on Hybrid developement where I found out that you can have two options when you go Hybrid. Hybrid-local, where you install your html and js files locally or Hybrid-remote, where you put everything in the cloud as visual force pages and static resources. The webinar explained that if you wanted offline smartstore you need to use the hybrid-local approach and that it is difficult to use offline in the hybrid-remote approach.

But then we found an example app on Josh Birk's GitHub account called [WarehousePhoneOffline](https://github.com/joshbirk/WarehousePhone) which is Hybrid-remote with SmartStore.

We tried to implement the WarehousePhoneOffline example, we installed it on our developer org and it runs but we don't get any results or errors back.

So, the question is simple. Can anyone confirm you can use SmartStore in an Hybrid-remote approach? Maybe also give some direction to examples or documentation on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2013/04/access-mobile-device-functionality-with-javascript-and-cordova.html

Here is the nice reference ,if you are looking to start.

```
https://github.com/joshbirk/WarehousePhone
```

Above github link how to use smartstore in visualforce based applications

```
<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.Cordova}"/>
<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.SFHybridApp}"/>
<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.SFSmartstorePlugin}"/>//Smartstore plugin in visualforce
```

Developing an offline app with smartstore visualforce based is definitely possible .An advantage of server based apps is changes reflect instantaneously and there is no need to package or build each time for small change as the change is directly on server .

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use smartstore when running in hybrid remote - I have an application that is based on Visualforce pages with the thinnest of wrappers on the phone, and I am saving user setup information in the smartstore.

The key here is that your Visualforce pages have to include the cordova and smartstore JavaScript files to be able to access the functionality correctly.  There's an additional wrinkle if you are using PIN codes too, in that you need to access the smartstore after the user has unlocked the application, otherwise you won't be able to decrypt it.